# GPS tracker for parcel?

Tags: gps, energy-efficient

The mail people where I live are very careless.  When I ship packages, unless I purchase insurance or send through registered mail, the packages tend to get lost very often.  The postal worker who receives packages even tells me, Are you  sure you want to send this as parcel post?  If it gets lost, you'll have no recourse, even though it has tracking...

I am tired of having to pay $6 to send a letter as insured.  Doesn't help that FedEx and UPS cost even more.  They always get lost locally, and cannot be found despite having a tracking number.  I suspect that they toss these letters in the trash, because they want people to purchase insurance.  Is there a GPS device I can put in a letter to mail, so that if it gets lost again, I can find where exactly it is, and file a complaint?

Features I need:

- Free or very low-cost tracking available, possibly with my data SIM.
- Can last 2 days on a battery: so that if it gets lost, I can find it.
- Relatively lightweight (first-class is 13 oz. max, so I want to fool them into thinking it's just a package like the ones I usually send).

Most GPS devices out there have (2) but not (1).  [This unit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00USOHD76) I found has (1), but its battery lasts 7-8 hours.

Comment: Please note that a long lasting lithium chemistry battery will violate US Postal Service regulations if sent as ordinary mail.

Comment: Hmm?  I read https://about.usps.com/postal-bulletin/2012/pb22336/html/updt_004.htm, and I don't see anything corroborating this... I mean, they cannot be high-capacity Lithium batteries (being high-capacity would make them more than 13 oz. anyways) -- but, long-lasting doesn't seem to be a problem.  I guess what I was looking for was, for the mA draw of the GPS to be low: hence the [energy-efficient] tag.